# Worklight app showing the text of the views on initialization

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I tried this many times but there is no use I create a worklight application with a main view and a list with items that opens other views (included in the same HTML file).

When I test the application on the mobile device (Samsung Galaxy S4) o on the browser it shows the complete content of the html file just for  second before the widgets render correctly.

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList"  class="indexListStyle" >
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="icon:'images/about.png',moveTo:'aboutView',variableHeight:true,transition:'fade'" class="indexListStyle">About </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="icon:'images/register.png',moveTo:'agendaView',variableHeight:true,transition:'slide'" class="indexListStyle">Agenda</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="icon:'images/register.png',moveTo:'registrationView',variableHeight:true,transition:'cover'" class="indexListStyle">Register</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="icon:'images/register.png',moveTo:'profileView',variableHeight:true,transition:'dissolve'" class="indexListStyle">GBM Profile</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="aboutView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

</div>
    <div id="agendaView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

</div>
<div id="registrationView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

</div>
<div id="profileView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

</div>
```

I load the contents of the view divs from external HTML files in the function wlCommonInit() like this

```
$("#aboutView").load("about.html");
```

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2):

Add style="visibility:hidden" to the HTML body tag.

the dojox/mobile framework should set this to visible once the parser has run.

Comment: It is working now thank you ironically the body has style "display:none" which is supposed to do the same

Comment: display:none on the body is updated by the Worklight infrastructure when Worklight is ready (which is before the dojo loading/parsing is done)  visibility:hidden on the body is updated by the dojo mobile framework when dojo is ready